# Pass a C Structure pointer from Python using Ctypes

Tags: python, c, pointers, structure, ctypes

I have a **yec.c** file defining a structure with two functions:

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

struct mec
{
    int age;
    int number;
};


static PyObject* nopoint(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    struct mec m;
    int n1, n2;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &n1, &n2))
        return NULL;

    printf("nopoint(c) nombres: %d et %d!\n", n1, n2);

    m.age = n1;
    m.number = n2;
    printf("nopoint(c) age nb: %d et %d!\n", m.age, m.number);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", n1 + n2);
}


static PyObject* viapoint(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    struct mec *m;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "o", &m))
        return NULL;

    printf("viapoint av(c) age nb: %d et %d!\n", m->age, m->number);

    m->age = 10;
    m->number = 1;
    printf("viapoint ap(c) age nb: %d et %d!\n", m->age, m->number);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", m->age + m->number);
}


static PyMethodDef MyYecMethods[] = {
    {"nopoint", nopoint, METH_VARARGS, "Description de fune"},
    {"viapoint", viapoint, METH_VARARGS, "Description de fdeux"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
inityec(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("yec", MyYecMethods);
}
```

I compiled the yec.c file into yec.so with a `python setup_yec.py build` command on the following **setup_yec.py** file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('yec', sources = ['yec.c'])

setup (name = 'YecPkg',
        version = '1.0',
        description = 'This is a demo of yec pkg',
        ext_modules = [module1])
```

I can use my compiled library under Python and the nopoint() function works:

```
import yec
yec.nopoint(3, 4)
```

I would like to use the second function ; viapoint() of my library which should accepts a struct pointer from Python where I define the related ctypes.Structure:

```
from ctypes import *

class Mec(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("age", c_int),
        ("number", c_int)]

m = Mec(1, 2)

print "py mec class", m.age, m.number

yec.viapoint(byref(m))
```

Of course, it does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testyec.py", line 18, in <module>
    yec.viapoint(byref(m))
TypeError: must be impossible<bad format char>, not CArgObject
```

If someone knows how to modify the viapoint() function to be able to parse the structure pointer via the PyArg_ParseTuple() and how to pass the python structure pointer in python (using byref?), it would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse the `Structure` as a read-write buffer (`"w#"`). By passing it as an argument you can rest assured that it's a referenced object. It also ensures that the passed in buffer is writable memory of the correct size. Crashing Python is not acceptable. You're supposed to get exceptions in Python. If you have Python code that makes it trivial to segfault the interpreter, you're doing it very wrong.

```
static PyObject* viapoint(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    struct mec *m;
    size_t size;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "w#", &m, &size))
        return NULL;

    if (size != sizeof(struct mec)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "wrong buffer size");
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("viapoint av(c) age nb: %d et %d!\n", m->age, m->number);
    m->age = 10;
    m->number = 1;

    return Py_BuildValue("i", m->age + m->number);
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *
import yec

class Mec(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("age", c_int),
        ("number", c_int),
    ]

class Bad(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("age", c_int),
        ("number", c_int),
        ("extra", c_int),
    ]

m = Mec(1, 2)
print yec.viapoint(m)

# TypeError
b = Bad(1, 2, 3)
print yec.viapoint(b)
```

---

If you just accept an address as the argument, your function might segfault on an invalid pointer, or just return garbage or modify memory that will make you program crash later in an inscrutable way. Moreover, by parsing the address you'll need to conditionally define whether to parse as `long` or `long long` in the preprocessor, depending on the size of `void *` compared to `long`. For example, on Win64 a `long` is 32bit and parsing a pointer as `long` truncates it. Finally, an API that requires you to first call `addressof` in Python is an inefficient kludge.

Comment: Ok, using the read-write buffer method is safer! I will change my code. Thanks.

Comment: If I would have created the structure in C, and return its pointer via a function in the c library. Do I simply store this in a variable in python or is there another trick to do in python to use it back in c as you described?

Comment: The method in my answer is just for Python objects that implement the buffer interface with a writable buffer. You can use it with ctypes data types, or NumPy arrays, and so on. The best way to smuggle a pointer through Python is to wrap it in a `PyCapsule`. Say you `malloc` the memory for the struct. Then create the capsule with a destructor that calls `free` on the pointer.

Comment: Ok, I will try the py_capusles. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have just seen that numpy allows us to send a data float array as c types: `data.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))`. Does it work the same way as for the struct mec with a read-write buffer in PyArg_ParseTuple?

Comment: The following NumPy array will work with the function in my answer: `data = np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.int32)`. For ctypes, `data.ctypes` can be used as an argument. ctypes uses its `_as_parameter_` attribute, which is a `c_void_p` pointing at the array's buffer. Though you should really decide whether you want an extension module (in C/C++ or Cython) or a dynamic extension using ctypes. If you're going to require a compiler anyway, you may as well go all the way.

Comment: Thanks once more. I am oging to start with the w# option but I will look seriously at capsules and cython.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `ctypes.addressof` from the Python script, rather than `ctypes.byref` (which is a different object from a C pointer), and then, in `yec.c`, parse the input value as a `long` (or `int` if in 32bits) and assign it to the "struct mec *".

See below a working example:

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

struct mec
{
    int age;
    int number;
};


static PyObject* nopoint(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    struct mec m;
    int n1, n2;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &n1, &n2))
        return NULL;

    printf("nopoint(c) nombres: %d et %d!\n", n1, n2);

    m.age = n1;
    m.number = n2;
    printf("nopoint(c) age nb: %d et %d!\n", m.age, m.number);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", n1 + n2);
}


static PyObject* viapoint(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    struct mec *m;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "l", &m))
        return NULL;

    printf("viapoint av(c) age nb: %d et %d!\n", m->age, m->number);

    m->age = 10;
    m->number = 1;
    printf("viapoint ap(c) age nb: %d et %d!\n", m->age, m->number);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", m->age + m->number);
}


static PyMethodDef MyYecMethods[] = {
    {"nopoint", nopoint, METH_VARARGS, "Description de fune"},
    {"viapoint", viapoint, METH_VARARGS, "Description de fdeux"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
inityec(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("yec", MyYecMethods);
}
```

and in Python:

```
from ctypes import *
import yec


class Mec(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("age", c_int),
        ("number", c_int)]


m = Mec(1, 2)

print "py mec class", m.age, m.number

yec.viapoint(addressof(m))
```

Running it, I get:

```
> python run.py                                                                                   
py mec class 1 2
viapoint av(c) age nb: 1 et 2!
viapoint ap(c) age nb: 10 et 1!
```

Comment: Perfect, it works. It's easier for me to use this solution compared to the read-write buffer ("w#"). I wonder if it make a difference somehow to use the pointer as long or the read-write buffer option? By chance, I found that another way to play with c structures in python is to use PyCapsule. For people interested in this, here is a [link](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch15.html#capsules) I found.

Comment: Or you can use Cython, an amazing piece of software, in my opinion.

Comment: I got a ready to use c code from a colleague and I just wanted to handle the laborious pretreatment of the data in python. But I should take the time to have a look at cython! Thanks.